# Why Bootstrap footer is not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have use Bootstrap blog template but the footer is not working. Any help?
I copy the code from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/blog/

Header part and footer part is not in action.

Here is my code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Blog Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="blog-masthead">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="blog-nav">
                <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">New features</a>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="blog-header">
            <h1 class="blog-title">The Bootstrap Blog</h1>
            <p class="lead blog-description">The official example template of creating a blog with Bootstrap.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">

                <div class="blog-post">
                    <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post</h2>
                    <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a     href="#">ABC</a></p>


                    <hr>

                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
                    <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
                    <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
                    <pre><code>Example code block</code></pre>
                    <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
                    <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
                    <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. amet risus.</p>

                    <p>Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</li>
                        <li>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</li>
                        <li>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</li>
                    </ol>
                    <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.</p>
                </div><!-- /.blog-post -->





                <nav>
                    <ul class="pager">
                        <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div><!-- /.blog-main -->

            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 blog-sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-module sidebar-module-inset">
                    <h4>About</h4>
                    <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur .</p>
                </div>


            </div><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->

        </div><!-- /.row -->

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <footer class="blog-footer">
        <p>Blog template built for <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a> by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
        <p>
            <a href="#">Back to top</a>
        </p>
    </footer>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>
```

I have use Bootstrap blog template but the footer is not working. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this you are missing blog.css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Blog Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/blog/blog.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="blog-masthead">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="blog-nav">
            <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">New features</a>

        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

    <div class="blog-header">
        <h1 class="blog-title">The Bootstrap Blog</h1>
        <p class="lead blog-description">The official example template of creating a blog with Bootstrap.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">

            <div class="blog-post">
                <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post</h2>
                <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a     href="#">ABC</a></p>


                <hr>

                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
                <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
                <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
                <pre><code>Example code block</code></pre>
                <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
                <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
                <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. amet risus.</p>

                <p>Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
                <ol>
                    <li>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</li>
                    <li>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</li>
                    <li>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</li>
                </ol>
                <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.</p>
            </div><!-- /.blog-post -->





            <nav>
                <ul class="pager">
                    <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div><!-- /.blog-main -->

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 blog-sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-module sidebar-module-inset">
                <h4>About</h4>
                <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur .</p>
            </div>


        </div><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->

    </div><!-- /.row -->

</div><!-- /.container -->

<footer class="blog-footer">
    <p>Blog template built for <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a> by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
    <p>
        <a href="#">Back to top</a>
    </p>
</footer>


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

put this css in your style sheet or in page

```
.blog-footer {
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

You are missing blog.css also so can download from here and integrate in your code
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/blog/blog.css

have a look in code pen now it is working

http://codepen.io/santoshkhalse/pen/ozWaNA

Comment: Thanks, Its woking but I have one more issue. Footer part come just after where page end but I want it in bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is because you are missing an additional CSS file used by that template site.

If you go to the link you provided and inspect the source you will see the file "blog.css".

This will work once you have that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this css file - http://getbootstrap.com/examples/blog/blog.css
,missing **blog.css**

```
.blog-footer {
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
```

```css
   /*
 * Globals
 */

body {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #555;
}

h1, .h1,
h2, .h2,
h3, .h3,
h4, .h4,
h5, .h5,
h6, .h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #333;
}


/*
 * Override Bootstrap's default container.
 */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
width: 970px;
  }
}


/*
 * Masthead for nav
 */

.blog-masthead {
  background-color: #428bca;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
      box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

/* Nav links */
.blog-nav-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #cdddeb;
}
.blog-nav-item:hover,
.blog-nav-item:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Active state gets a caret at the bottom */
.blog-nav .active {
  color: #fff;
}
.blog-nav .active:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: " ";
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}


/*
 * Blog name and description
 */

.blog-header {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.blog-title {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.blog-description {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #999;
}


/*
 * Main column and sidebar layout
 */

.blog-main {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

/* Sidebar modules for boxing content */
.sidebar-module {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 -15px 15px;
}
.sidebar-module-inset {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.sidebar-module-inset p:last-child,
.sidebar-module-inset ul:last-child,
.sidebar-module-inset ol:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* Pagination */
.pager {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: left;
}
.pager > li > a {
  width: 140px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
}


/*
 * Blog posts
 */

.blog-post {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.blog-post-title {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.blog-post-meta {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #999;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */

.blog-footer {
  padding: 40px 0;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.blog-footer p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>

    <div class="blog-masthead">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="blog-nav">
                <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">New features</a>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="blog-header">
            <h1 class="blog-title">The Bootstrap Blog</h1>
            <p class="lead blog-description">The official example template of creating a blog with Bootstrap.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">

                <div class="blog-post">
                    <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post</h2>
                    <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a     href="#">ABC</a></p>


                    <hr>

                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
                    <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
                    <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
                    <pre><code>Example code block</code></pre>
                    <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
                    <h3>Sub-heading</h3>
                    <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. amet risus.</p>

                    <p>Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</li>
                        <li>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</li>
                        <li>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</li>
                    </ol>
                    <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.</p>
                </div><!-- /.blog-post -->





                <nav>
                    <ul class="pager">
                        <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div><!-- /.blog-main -->

            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 blog-sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-module sidebar-module-inset">
                    <h4>About</h4>
                    <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur .</p>
                </div>


            </div><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->

        </div><!-- /.row -->

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <footer class="blog-footer">
        <p>Blog template built for <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a> by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
        <p>
            <a href="#">Back to top</a>
        </p>
    </footer>
```